# Cannot update SQL database

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

So I created an edit profile page and everything went fine. But later on I wanted to use similar code to update another thing inside my database. Its a very odd bugg because when I add to many values that need to be update it refuse to work.

```
<?php

session_start();

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$Creator = $_SESSION['username'];
$dbName = $_POST['Name'];
$dbBase_damage = $_POST['Base_damage'];
$dbDamage = $_POST['Damage'];
$dbPellets = $_POST['Pellets'];
$dbAttackspeed = $_POST['Attackspeed'];
$dbRS = $_POST['RS(first)'];
$dbRS2 = $_POST['RS(consecutive)'];
$dbLoaded = $_POST['Loaded'];
$dbReserve = $_POST['Reserve'];
$dbCritical = $_POST['Critical'];
$dbAbility = $_POST['Ability'];
$dbPiece_set = $_POST['Piece_set'];
$dbBonus_set = $_POST['Bonus_set'];
$dbDescription = $_POST['Description'];

if ($dbName && $dbBase_damage && $dbDamage && $dbAttackspeed && $dbLoaded && $dbCritical) {

mysql_connect ("localhost", "root", "") or die ("Could not connect");
mysql_select_db("weapons") or die ("Could not connect to the database");    

$wepquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM weapon WHERE Creator='$Creator' AND Name='$dbName'") or die ("The query could not be completed, please try again later!");
if (mysql_num_rows($wepquery) != 0) {

mysql_query ("

UPDATE weapon SET Base_Damage='$dbBase_damage', Damage='$dbDamage', 
Pellets='$dbPellets', Attackspeed='$dbAttackspeed', RS(first)='$dbRS', RS(consecutive)='$dbRS2', 
Loaded='$dbLoaded', Reserve='$dbReserve', Critical='$dbCritical', Ability='$dbAbility', Piece_set='$dbPiece_set', 
Bonus_set='$dbBonus_set' Description='$dbDescription' WHERE Creator='$Creator' AND Name='$dbName'

") or die ("Could not update!");
echo "It just werks!";

}else echo ("That username could not be found!");
}else echo ("Something went wrong!"); 
    }
    ?>
```

When I use this code I get an error that 'Base_Damage' is undefined index. But when I remove 'Base_Damage', it can not update at all. I have double checked the database and created 'weapon ideas' with it without problems. But for some reason when I reduce the amount of values that need to be update it works just fine. If you wonder about the "$Creator = $_SESSION['username'];", I get the Creator username depending on who is logged in from "nav.php"
My html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0" />
<title>TF2 NUT</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
</head>

<div id="Container">

<div id="header">
<h1>Welcome to TF2 NUT!</h1>
</div>

<div id="nav">

<?php

include_once "nav.php";

?>

</div>

<div id="Content">
<h2>Update your submissions</h2>
<form action="edit_sub.php" method="POST">
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
    Choose weapon to edit: 
    </td>
    <td>
    <input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
    Base damage: 
    </td>
    <td>
    <input type="text" name="Base_damage" id="Base_damage" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
    Damage: 
    </td>
    <td>
    <input type="text" name="Damage" id="Damage" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
    Pellets: 
    </td>
    <td>
    <input type="text" name="Pellets" id="Pellets" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
    Attackspeed: 
    </td>
    <td>
    <input type="text" name="Attackspeed" id="Attackspeed" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
    Reload speed: 
    </td>
    <td>
    <input type="text" name="RS(first)" id="RS(first)" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
    Reload(consecutive): 
    </td>
    <td>
    <input type="text" name="RS(consecutive)" id="RS(consecutive)" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
    Loaded: 
    </td>
    <td>
    <input type="text" name="Loaded" id="Loaded" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
    Reserve: 
    </td>
    <td>
    <input type="text" name="Reserve" id="Reserve" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
    Critical: 
    </td>
    <td>
    <input type="text" name="Critical" id="Critical" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
    Ability: 
    </td>
    <td>
    <input type="text" name="Ability" id="Ability" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
    Piece set: 
    </td>
    <td>
    <input type="text" name="Piece_set" id="Piece_set" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
    Bonus set: 
    </td>
    <td>
    <input type="text" name="Bonus_set" id="Bonus_set" />
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
Description:
<br />
<textarea style="resize: none;" rows="8" cols="40" id="Descripton" name="Description"></textarea>
<br />
<input type='submit' name="submit" value='Update' />
</form>
</div>

<div id="aside">

</div>

<div id="footer">

<h6>Responsible for the stuff on this site is Anton Magnusson</h6>
<h6>If I have done something wrong(I hope not ;_;) just contact me:   anton_peace@hotmail.com</h6>

</div>

</div>
```

Anyone can help? :P

Comment: first thing is that you should definitely stop using mysql_ commands as they will be depricated in the near future. Instead use mysqli or PDO.

Comment: So, you get an error from the query but when you edit the query it works?  Sounds like the query either has a syntax error or is referencing a database object that doesn't exist.  Format the query for readability and show the structure of the database table.

Comment: 1) Post table structure 2) this may be a case sensitivity problem, enclose fields names in `-s

Comment: You're looking for `$_POST['Base_Damage']`. Your form has it as `Base_damage`. PHP is case sensitive for variable names.

Comment: you are not getting any message or error ?

Comment: I have fixed my missed letter, but whenever I try again it only says:
"Could not update!"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i guess your if statment is not readable and thats why you couldnt update

- first your name `name="Base_damage"` ia not same as your variable index `$dbBase_Damage = $_POST['Base_Damage'];`

it should be

```
    $dbBase_Damage = $_POST['Base_damage']; // with small d
```

try replave this also

```
     if ($dbName && $dbBase_Damage && $dbDamage && $dbAttackspeed && $dbLoaded && $dbCritical)
```

**edit:**

in your query replace this

```
     RS(first)='$dbRS', RS(consecutive)='$dbRS2'
```

by

```
      `RS(first)`='$dbRS', `RS(consecutive)`='$dbRS2'
```

**EDIT2:**

please replace

```
      or die ("Could not update!");
```

with

```
   or die(mysql_error()); // like that you can see what error or what goes wrong.
```

**EDIT3.**

```
     Bonus_set='$dbBonus_set' , Description=
                             ^^//you missed coma here
```

Comment: because there is someone who called `strawberry` who judges and reclams for the reputation of others. post your answer and get reputations. and stop talking about reputation of others

Comment: I have fixed my problem with the letters but I still get an error.
I have tried to post a picture with my table structure but I can't because I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: Can still not update. Do you think it have something to do with my database and my variables?

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Description='Nothing' WHERE Creator='Atosag' AND Name='Scatter'' at line 4

Comment: you have missed a comma before description

Comment: wow what a horrible mistake. Thank you so much for having patience to help me! I love you! It worked!!